# Customize DatePickerDialog on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to edit the android DatePickerDialog from Xamarin. I can edit general parameters like main background without problems, but I can't do it for specific things.
What I'm looking for is change the background only for certain days of the week, or to do a multiple highlighting.

Looking for how to do it, most people recommend using third-party controls but these are not work with I need.

someone knows a way to overwrite DatePickerDialog creation?
just to change the background or text color only for some days of the week?

Comment: you need to write a custom renderer

Comment: Hi Jason,
yeah, with a custom render I can change entire background successfully. But I can't find a way to change background only for a specific days (or days of week).

Comment: Unfortunately, I see no mention anywhere of Android DatePicker having an option to change only *some* day-columns or dates. Nor to highlight multiple dates.

Comment: Hi Steve. you are right, no default options on datapicker for this. I looking for do with a custom render, but I didn't found which member overried to get this. I reach to modify main and header background but not only "particular cells" from days grid

Comment: For the built-in DatePicker(actually here is CalendarView) , there is no method to modify the backgroundcolor of specific dates , you will need to implement your own datepicker or search third-party plugins for alternative .

Answer (score 0):

Create a new control using rg popup, you'll get the same UI on all platforms and easy control over bindings